# How to use subquery in a IN() clause in where part of HQL?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a simple class:

```
public class Chat {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

}
```

and a couple of inherited classes:

```
public class GroupChat extends Chat{
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany()
    private List<User> users;

}
```

and

```
public class PrivateChat extends Chat{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_user_id")
    private User firstUser;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_user_id")
    private User secondUser;
}
```

I am trying to make a query that would return all the chats that a particular user is. The way i see it is something like:

```
"select c from Chat c " +
"join PrivateChat pc on c.id = pc.id " +
"join GroupChat gc on gc.id = c.id " +
"where pc.firstUser = :user or pc.secondUser = :user "
+
"or :user IN(gc.users)"
```

I also tried a few other ways but can't make it work. How do i check if the userID is in a list that is a field of an entity ?

Comment: Try to remove brackets. - "IN gc.users"